when is .bashrc read?
I have been scratching my head trying to figure out why & how my ~/.bashrc file is read :/
I'm connecting to my Debian bookworm server through ssh. It's an interactive login shell.
According to man page ~/.bashrc is read & executes only when it's an interactive  shell  that  is not a login shell (or when  it's non-interactive but through sshd)
In bash man page :

When  bash  is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in  that  order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

I've none of the files  ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile. So I check /etc/profile. It reads /etc/bash.bashrc that has no mention to ~/.bashrc
So really, I don't understand how my ~/.bashrc is executed. Which script invokes it ?

Are you sure you don't have a ~/.profile? There is one by default, and the default .profile reads ~/.bashrc.

Go two paragraphs down after that text?

"or when it's non-interactive but through sshd" - that is not in the quoted text. The manpage states "or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option". For example, non-interactive are shells that execute scripts or commands. So, if you executed bash --login my_script.sh, that would fit the description. sshd runs an interactive login shell unless ssh is given a command as a parameter.

The reading of ~/.bashrc is described two paragraphs down from what you are reading. It is read when Bash is started as an interactive non-login shell.
To have ~/.bashrc read by the login shell, you put something like this into the ~/.bash_profile:
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

I think some GNU/Linux distros set this up for newly created accounts; you may already have it.
